# How to resolve pypi/ pyserial installation warning for setup.py 'unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3'"

Tags: installation, syntax-error, pyserial, pypi

I am installing pyserial2.7 using

```
python install setup.py
```

and get the warning "unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3'"
after this warning, it gives a set  of running.... install, build and so on.
However,

```
import.serial
```

inside python, gives invalid syntax error.
I guess, the pyserial did not install properly. How do I resolve this ?
I am using Python 2.7 on debian , if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> python install setup.py

The correct syntax is

```
python setup.py install
```

> import.serial

The correct syntax is

```
import serial
```

PySerial 2.7 is rather old version, the current version is 3.4.